# Boundedness assumption for isomorphism between some derived functors in Kashiwara and Schapira

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a sheaf of ring on a topological space, and denote $\mathbf{D}^+(\mathscr{R})$ (resp. $\mathbf{D}^-(\mathscr{R})$, $\mathbf{D}^b(\mathscr{R})$) to be the bounded below (resp. bounded above, bounded) derived category of sheaves of $\mathscr{R}$-modules.
In the book Sheaves on Manifolds of Kashiwara and Schapira, they define the derived sheaf How, $R \mathscr{H}om(\cdot,\cdot): \mathbf{D}^- (\mathscr{R})^\circ \times \mathbf{D}^+ (\mathscr{R}) \rightarrow \mathbf{D}^+ (\mathscr{R})$ by replacing the second component by quasi-isomorphic injective sheaves. 
And they define the derived global section functor, $R\Gamma:\mathbf{D}^+ (\mathscr{R}) \rightarrow \mathbf{D}^+ (\mathscr{R})$ and the derived Hom, $R Hom(\cdot,\cdot): \mathbf{D}^- (\mathscr{R})^\circ \times \mathbf{D}^+ (\mathscr{R}) \rightarrow \mathbf{D}^+ (Ab)$ similarly.

But to get the isomorphism 
$RHom(F,G) \cong R\Gamma(X;R\mathscr{H}om(F,G))$, they assume without explanation that $F$ is in $\mathbf{D}^b(\mathscr{R})$. The same assumption is made when discussing relation between $R\mathscr{H}om$ and $Rf_\ast$. 
Can someone verify if this assumption is redundant or not? If this assumption is essential, what's the reason?

Thank you

Comment: These isomorphisms follow from using the Grothendieck spectral sequence, right? If I remember correctly, the issue is that the Grothendieck spectral sequence needs complexes to be bounded below. The relevant proposition in Kashiwara–Schapira is Prop. 1.10.9.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The condition for Prop. 1.10.9, in Kashiwara-Schapira is bounded below for both component. By when they apply this proposition to, for example, Equation (2.6.3), Equation (2.6.24)-(2.6.26), Prop. 3.1.10, etc., they need to assume the first component to be bounded on both side. Not only bounded below. And that's the place I got confused.

Comment: Sorry, Equation (2.6.3) was a typo. What I want to mention was equation (2.6.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Kashiwara and Schapira wrote "Sheaves on Manifolds", the theory of unbounded categories was not known (or very little known, I do not know for certain) and that is why the framework of the book is the bounded derived category $\textbf{D}^b$ or the bounded from below $\textbf{D}^+$ derived category. For the applications they had in mind, $\textbf{D}^b$ was enough and most of the book is written in this framework, which does not mean that some results do not extend to $\textbf{D}^+$. Consider the following example.

> But to get the isomorphism 
>   $RHom(F,G) \cong R\Gamma(X;R\mathscr{H}om(F,G))$, they assume without explanation that $F$ is in $\mathbf{D}^b(\mathscr{R})$.

In the above, Kashiwara and Schapira could have assumed $F \in \textbf{D}^-$, but in practice they always have $F \in \textbf{D}^b$.

> The same assumption is made when discussing relation between $R\mathscr{H}om$ and $Rf_\ast$. 
>   Can someone verify if this assumption is redundant or not? If this assumption is essential, what's the reason?
>
> These isomorphisms follow from using the Grothendieck spectral sequence, right? If I remember correctly, the issue is that the Grothendieck spectral sequence needs complexes to be bounded below. The relevant proposition in Kashiwara–Schapira is Prop. 1.10.9.
>
> That's what I'm saying. The condition for Prop. 1.10.9, in Kashiwara-Schapira is bounded below for both component. By when they apply this proposition to, for example, Equation (2.6.3), Equation (2.6.24)-(2.6.26), Prop. 3.1.10, etc., they need to assume the first component to be bounded on both side. Not only bounded below. And that's the place I got confused.

I do not understand your objection. In Proposition 1.10.9, the result is stated in $\textbf{D}^+$ and this is the situation of (2.6.3), etc.

A final remark. In the book, derived functors are treated in the unbounded case.

> Sorry, (2.6.3) is a typo. What I wanted to mention was (2.6.4) and the result is stated in $D^b \times D^+$. For other equation, they also assume this $D^b \times D^+$ condition and that's what confused me because they assumed $D^+ \times D^+$ in Proposition 1.10.9.

Since $\text{Hom}$ is contravariant with respect to the first variable, perhaps the result can be extended to $\textbf{D}^- \times \textbf{D}^+$ but certainly not $\textbf{D}^+\times \textbf{D}^+$ (unless we use other tools such as those of "Categories and Sheaves" GL Springer 2006, see [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kashiwara2.pdf)).

Kashiwara, Masaki; Schapira, Pierre. **Categories and sheaves.** Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften [Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences], 332. *Springer-Verlag*, *Berlin*, 2006. x+497 pp.

Comment: Sorry, (2.6.3) is a typo. What I wanted to mention was (2.6.4) and the result is stated in $D^b \times D^+$. For other equation, they also assume this $D^b \times D^+$ condition and that's what confused me because they assumed $D^+ \times D^+$ in proposition 1.10.9.

Comment: I forget to mention, they sometimes identify $D^{-}$ with $D^{+}$ of the opposite category.